# html, css: how to link label to page with on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css

I have HTML with a table and label below. All items are centered on the page and linked to the page width. It looks nice on PC, but when I open it on the phone it looks a bit wrong, looks like page less, but linked to table width, and the rest items look like center on page less size:

[image]

Please advise how to link the label to the actual page width and also how to center the caption in real page width.

CSS:

```
h1 {

    color: #0b2e13;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 340%;

}

table {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 3px solid darkblue;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 5px 10px;
    width: 1000px;
}

label {
    position: static ;
    width: 95%;
    font-size: 250%;
    margin: 1%;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    text-align: justify;
    font-weight: bold;

}
```

HTML is too big, in short, its:

```
<h1> CAPTION </h1>
<table>
...
</table>

<label>
...
</label>
```

Comment: you should share you html and css code and describe in more detail what is wrong and how you want it to be (maybe show how it looks an PC and how it looks on mobile and how it should look, by using paint or similar)

Comment: I updated question with css and html in short.

Comment: maybe it is possible to set minimum label width same with table? But how to center caption in same page size as a table?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you found *a* solution, but I'm not sure if that's really what you want to do... In most cases, setting a `min-width` on the `<body>` isn't a good idea. Maybe that's fine with you, but this is how I would recommend doing it:

```css
*,
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.table-container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
caption {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
td {
  min-width: 60px;
  width: min-content;
  height: 20px;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.label {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 25rem;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <div class='table-container'>
    
    <table>
    
      <caption>some text in caption</caption>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    
  </div>

  <div class="label">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Granted, I don't know your full use case. This is just my take on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is much better then my solution

Answer (score 0):

I found solution: just added  to css >>>body {min-width: 1200px;}<<< and now all elements in center with any scale on page, and never less than table (1200 - total table width)